# How to call JavaScript function in HTML from external script

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function in my html in script tags.  I want to call this function from another JavaScript function that is declared in an external JavaScript file.  Assuming function1 is in the script tags, and function2 is calling it from the external file, what is the correct syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming function1 is defined before function2 calls it, and function1 takes no parameters:

```
function1();
```

Comment: if it's this simple i'm going to feel really stupid.  haha